# Query for documents where dependent array size matches a value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following schema:

```
Collection1
  name
  slug
Collection2
  name
  slugCollection1
```

The "link" between `Collection1` and `Collection2` is through fields `slug` and `slugCollection1`.

I try to implement a request with the aggregation framework of MongoDB to get all elements of `Collection1` that have a specific name and number of dependent elements of type `Collection2`.

I can get the hints leveraging `$project`:

```
[
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Collection2",
      "localField": "slug",
      "foreignField": "slugCollection1",
      "as": "elements"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "id": "$id",
      "name": 1,
      "slug": 1,
      "elementsNumber": {
        "$size": "$elements"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But I can't use the `elementsNumber` field into `$match` later. I guess that it's because it's not a field part of the `Collection1`.

Is there a way to implement such query?
Thanks!

Comment: What makes you say you can't use the new field `elementsNumber` within a `$match` pipeline? Of course it's possible; `{ "$match": { "elementsNumber": { "$gt": 3 } } }` for example...

Comment: Thanks very much @chridam for the hint! After investigating a bit more this issue, I found out that I used a number instead of an integer for the criteria. Switching to integer fixed the problem! Your hint about the ability to do that helped me. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can of course use a **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline to filter the documents with the given criteria as:

```
[
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "Collection2",
            "localField": "slug",
            "foreignField": "slugCollection1",
            "as": "elements"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "id": "$id",
            "name": 1,
            "slug": 1,
            "elementsNumber": { "$size": "$elements" }
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "elementsNumber": { "$gt": 3 } } }
]
```